# Package 'python-pip' not found in suse linux

Tags: python, suse

I am new to Linux and I am trying to install python package in SUSE Linux. I tried below options

Option 1:

```
zypper install python-pip
Loading repository data...
Warning: No repositories defined. Operating only with the installed resolvables. Nothing can be installed.
Reading installed packages...
Package 'python-pip' not found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Option 2:

```
python get-pip.py
python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I already have python installed but I see multiple python files in /usr/bin. Could it be the reason

```
# find / -executable -name 'python*'
/home/db2inst1/sqllib/python32
/home/db2inst1/sqllib/python64
/usr/include/python2.7
/usr/lib64/python
/usr/lib64/python2.7
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/share/doc/packages/python-pycparser
/usr/share/doc/packages/python-Jinja2
/usr/share/doc/packages/python-pyzmq
/usr/share/doc/packages/python-PyYAML
/usr/share/doc/packages/python-pyasn1
/usr/share/doc/packages/python-gobject2
/usr/share/doc/packages/python-gobject
/usr/share/doc/packages/python-psutil
/usr/share/licenses/python-requests
/usr/share/licenses/python-cffi
/usr/share/licenses/python-PyYAML
/usr/share/licenses/python-certifi
/usr/share/licenses/python-cryptography
/usr/share/licenses/python-singledispatch
/usr/lib/python2.6
/usr/lib/rpm/python-macro-helper
/usr/lib/rpm/pythondeps.sh
/usr/lib/python2.7
/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/dsdriver/python32
/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/dsdriver/python64
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with SUSE, but one thing to note is that Python 2 is no longer supported. If you have the option (i.e. if you're not locked into maintaining legacy software), Python 3 is highly preferred. It's probably a separate package in your distro, likely `python3`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this:

1. First search if your internal SUSE repos provide the desired package

   zypper search "package-name"
2. If yes, then first install python3 packages using

   zypper install --force-resolution "python3"
   zypper install --force-resolution "python3-pip"
3. Once you have them installed then you can run below

   python3 -m pip install "package-name"

Similarly, for other packages.